# Filtering array and then map array in array

Tags: javascript

Pretty sure that I am missing something simple but this code has me banging my head.

I have an `array` in a local `json` file as

```
{
  "type": [
    {
      "name": "Accommodation",
      "icon": "",
      "subcategory": [
        "Hotels",
        "Motels",
        "Bed & Breakfasts"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Guided Tours",
      "icon": "",
      "subcategory": [
        "Audio & Self Guided",
        "Cruises, Sailing & Water",
        "Food, Wine & Nightlife"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and importing into a React component as

```
import { type } from './assets/json/company-type.json';
```

then I am using `filter` to the `name` of `companyType` (which is based on a `select` value of either `Accommodation` or `Guided Tours`. After I map the returned items before `map` the `subcategory`

```
<ul>
  {type
    .filter(item => {
      return item.name === companyType;
    })
    .map(item => {
      item.subcategory.map(subcategory => {
        <li key={subcategory}>
          <label id={subcategory} htmlFor={subcategory}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name={subcategory}
              value={subcategory}
            />
            <span />
            {subcategory}
          </label>
        </li>;
      });
    })}
</ul>
```

However, nothing is returned. Yet if I `log` `subcategory` I get each returned in the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not returning from .map() methods. 
Use this modified code and it will work as expected

```
<ul>
    {type
      .filter(item => {
        return item.name === "Accommodation";
      })
      .map(item => {
        return item.subcategory.map(subcategory => {
          return (
            <li key={subcategory}>
              <label id={subcategory} htmlFor={subcategory}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name={subcategory}
                  value={subcategory}
                />
                <span />
                {subcategory}
              </label>
            </li>
          );
        });
      })}
 </ul>
```

codeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/4881483j7x